# I'm missing the second line in a ggplot, there should be test and train lines present?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, curve

I'm trying to use ggplot2 using R to graph a train and test curve for the iterative error rates of a neural network. There should be two lines but I'm only seeing just the test line, does anyone know what happened? It looks like when I used `head(error_df)` every type is labelled as test for some reason.

**Edit:** even with just error_df without any subsets it's still not showing the line for the training set's error, this also includes various ranges such as error_df[2500:5000, 7500:10000,]

Here's the ggplot graph:

[image: ggplot graph]

Here's the code and [this is a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRPfNXLn8QmFQonm33DCkg3DjrqHJzEaXT_R0CpTNWw/edit?usp=sharing) to a public google spreadsheet of the data:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RSNNS)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotROC)
library(tidyr)

setwd("**set working directory**")
data <- read.csv("WDBC.csv", header=T)
data <- data[,1:4]
data <- scale(data)  # normalizes the data

numHneurons3 = 3
DecTargets = decodeClassLabels(data[,4])
train.test3 <- splitForTrainingAndTest(data, DecTargets,ratio = 0.50) # split

model3_02 <- mlp(train.test3$inputsTrain, train.test3$targetsTrain,  # build model3
                 size = numHneurons3, learnFuncParams = c(0.02),maxit = 10000, 
                 inputsTest = train.test3$inputsTest, 
                 targetsTest = train.test3$targetsTest)

#--------------------------------------
#     GGPlots of the Iterative Error:
#--------------------------------------

str(model3_02)

test_error <- model3_02$IterativeTestError
train_error <- model3_02$IterativeFitError

error_df <- data.frame(iter = c(seq_along(test_error),
                                seq_along(train_error)),
                       Error = c(test_error, train_error), 
                       type = c(rep("test", length(test_error)),
                                rep("train", length(train_error))
                       ))

ggplot(error_df[5000:10000,], aes(iter, Error, color = type, each = length(test_error))) + geom_line()
```

Here's also a snippet of the data, model, and data frame:

```
> head(data, 10)
       PatientID     radius    texture   perimeter
 [1,] -0.2361973  1.0960995 -2.0715123  1.26881726
 [2,] -0.2361956  1.8282120 -0.3533215  1.68447255
 [3,]  0.4313615  1.5784992  0.4557859  1.56512598
 [4,]  0.4317407 -0.7682333  0.2535091 -0.59216612
 [5,]  0.4318215  1.7487579 -1.1508038  1.77501133
 [6,] -0.2361855 -0.4759559 -0.8346009 -0.38680772
 [7,] -0.2361809  1.1698783  0.1605082  1.13712450
 [8,]  0.4326197 -0.1184126  0.3581350 -0.07280278
 [9,] -0.2361759 -0.3198854  0.5883121 -0.18391855
[10,]  0.4329621 -0.4731182  1.1044669 -0.32919213

> str(model3_02)
List of 17
 $ nInputs              : int 4
 $ maxit                : num 10000
 $ IterativeFitError    : num [1:10000] 18838 4468 2365 1639 1278 ...
 $ IterativeTestError   : num [1:10000] 7031 3006 1916 1431 1161 ...
 $ fitted.values        : num [1:284, 1:522] 0.00386 0.00386 0.00387 0.00387 0.00386 ...
 $ fittedTestValues     : num [1:285, 1:522] 0.00387 0.00387 0.00387 0.00387 0.00387 ...
 $ nOutputs             : int 522
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "mlp" "rsnns"

> head(error_df)  
  iter     Error type
1    1 7031.3101 test
2    2 3006.4253 test
3    3 1915.8997 test
4    4 1430.6152 test
5    5 1160.6987 test
6    6  990.2686 test
```

Comment: Have you checked `error_df` to see if there are rows where the `type` is `train`? Specifically in the rows you specify, `error_df[5000:10000,]`? `ggplot` is very good at plotting the data you give it. Since `train` doesn't show up in the legend, you probably didn't give it any rows where `train` shows up. Probably the `train` rows are not in the 5000:10000 range. I would suggest subsetting based on `iter` value rather than row number, something like `subset(error_df, iter > 5000 & iter <= 10000)`.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because they're split into subsets, so far I've tried rerunning different subsets and then trying to see the entire thing but most rows are omitted with 10,000 results, but so far I'm just seeing test. Shouldn't test and train be about the same, or maybe split down the middle? @GregorThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a data frame (`error_df`) with three columns by concatenating two variable together into one column, thus the variables were filled one after the other. However, you're limiting your plot from rows 5000 to 10000 of the data.

`ggplot(error_df[c(5000:10000, 15000:20000),], aes(iter, Error, color = type, each = length(test_error))) + geom_line()`

should show both curves.

Comment: I tried out ```error_df[c(2500:5000, 7500:10000),]``` but I'm still only getting a test line, it's a large V-shape so I'm assuming earlier on there's a large amount of error and then later there's less error

Comment: I also just did a general error_df and I'm still just getting test, it's in the shape of a giant L at a 90 degree angle, I'm assuming the training set is somehow being completely omitted

Comment: Check your `error_df` data frame. It has 20000 rows. the first 10000 rows are the test_error values the next 10000 rows are the train_error values. You keep choosing to plot only test_error values that is why you are seeing only test values in your plot.  Don't subset and see all the results or subset choosing same inter from both variables.

Comment: omg I'm dumb thanks, I didn't know to add 10,000 plus 10,000 to get the full number of rows